NX :: Include shared assets in an app's project.json
I have made an assets lib in my nrwl/nx repo at libs/shared/assets now I want to use those assets in my react app monday-rv-item. Below is the project.json for that app.
I am following these instructions; however, I dont have a build target so how can i do it without overwriting the existing build logic
https://nx.dev/recipes/tips-n-tricks/include-assets-in-build
Im building like this. npx nx build my-app --prod; however the solutions needs to work in prod and dev. So far i cant get it to work in dev.

how do i update the project json (if at all)?
how do i use the asset in html?

apps/monday-rv-item/project.json
{
  "name": "monday-rv-item",
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",
  "sourceRoot": "apps/monday-rv-item/src",
  "projectType": "application",
  "tags": [],
  "targets": {
    "test": {
      "executor": "@nx/jest:jest",
      "outputs": ["{workspaceRoot}/coverage/{projectRoot}"],
      "options": {
        "jestConfig": "apps/monday-rv-item/jest.config.ts"
      }
    }
  }
}


libs/shared/assets


You should be able to just import them inside the react project with a relative path like import  assets from ../../../libs/shared/assets/assets if the long path bothers you then create a alias using ts paths

how are you building and serving? please include this

I built with npx nx build my-app --prod; however it wont work in dev either.
